# Display all mysql data in rows one by one

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fetching all the records from mysql but it split in to rows as shown in the image [image: Imege1]

I want that it display row wise means the column which are splitting in the column means "future of india" and GAURAV should come in line now row wise. When the body part full it auto split into new row. here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category order by id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo '<table width="30%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="rcorners2"><a href="home.php?page=category&category='.$row["category"].'">'.$row["category"].'</a> </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You've got `<tr>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>` in your while...fetch loop. The <TR> tag starts a new table row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<span>` instead of`<div>` in the `<td>` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category order by id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          // output data of each row
              echo '<table width="30%" border="0">
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                <tr>
                  <td>
                     <div id="rcorners2"><a href="home.php?page=category&category='.$row["category"].'">'.$row["category"].'</a> </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>";
              }
              echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take table wrap all rows.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category order by id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        echo '<table width="30%" border="0">'
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td><div id="rcorners2"><a href="home.php?page=category&category='.$row["category"].'">'.$row["category"].'</a> </div></td>
                </tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I'll write pseudocode

```
<table>
  <tr>
      $query = "..."
      while ($row = fetch()) {
          <td>
              print row data
          </td>
      }
  </tr>
</table>
```